# Scaling background image in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know there's some plugins about for scaling a background image for a webpage, but this is a bit different.

I'm trying to get a div to resize proportionally, and have the background image inside also resize proportionally. It works for resizing horizontally.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <title></title>
 <style type="text/css" media="screen">

  body {
   background: #000;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   overflow-y: hidden;
  }
  #bg
  {
   z-index: -1;
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
  }

  #wrap
  {
   position: relative;
   margin: 0 auto;
  }
 </style>

</head>
<body>

 <div id="wrap">
  <img src="bg.jpg" id="bg" width="100%" />


  hi
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js">

 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

  var minWidth = 400;
  var minHeight = 400;
  var maxWidth = 500;
  var maxHeight = 500;

  function resize() {
   var windowWidth = $(window).width();
   var windowHeight = $(window).height();

   var w = windowWidth < minWidth ? minWidth :
   windowWidth > minWidth && windowWidth < maxWidth ? windowWidth :
   windowWidth > maxWidth ? maxWidth :
   minWidth;

   var h = windowHeight < minHeight ? minHeight :
   windowHeight > minHeight && windowHeight < maxHeight ? windowHeight :
   windowHeight > maxHeight ? maxHeight :
   minHeight;

   $("#wrap").css({
    'width': w + 'px',
    'height': h + 'px'
   });





  }

  $(document).ready(function() {

   resize();
      $(window).resize(function() {
        resize();
      });
  });


 </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The image in your example is not a background-image, but a regular IMG element. An background-image would be an CSS image.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using real background you can use ordinary `<img>` tag and emulate background by using absolute positioning.. proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/vu4Zh/

HTML code:

```
<div id="ImageContainer">
   <img class="background" src="mybackground.gif" border="0" />
    <div class="contents">
        Hello World
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#ImageContainer { width: 300px; position: relative; }
#ImageContainer .background { width: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1; }
#ImageContainer .contents { position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 99; }
```

By having this the image will automatically scale itself to its container, no script involved.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm not sure I made my intentions clear - there has to be a minimum and a maximum width and height for the container.

Comment: @htm what you mean by minimum and maximum? Who define those values and where? How should it be applied?

Answer (score 0):

You are stretching the div where the image is within (which is working properly). But the image has no percental height given and therefore it is not affected when the parent DIV is resized.

Comment: If only one dimension is put in, it will scale the image proportionally. I had a flag to change the dimension but jQuery wouldn't set the dimension to 100% (width or height).

Comment: Ah ok, I misunderstood you - I tried your example and had the problem that the resizing only worked when I made the window smaller horizontally whereas vertically didn't. It is not quite clear, what exactly your problem is. Maybe you can edit your original post and add an example.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to get it vertically also.